# Date validation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

It appear there is no validation rule in Laravel that `start_date` and  `end_date` can not be the same.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-date

Comment: Check the `different:field` rule. Might be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one in controller/model where you defined rules to check, and get the proper validation you want

```
Validator::extend('before_equal', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    return strtotime(Input::get($parameters[0])) >= strtotime($value);
});

$rules = array(
    'start'=>'required|date|before_equal:stop',
    'stop'=>'required|date',
);
```

Comment: this will compare dates by its string value, with help of strtotime

Comment: I am assuming `stop` is `end_date` ?

Comment: yes right :) start = start_date and stop = end_date

Comment: Thank you, how do I add custom validation error message for `before_equal` error?

Comment: by adding this validation rule to validation.php file for common use

Comment: file could be found at resources\lang\en\validation.php, do not forget to mark answer as accepted :P thanks in advance